# Google Sheets Query - Fetch data for calendar display

Tags: sql, google-sheets

I have a sheet with two rows of raw data  (serial # and delivery date).

On a second main sheet I want to show a calendar row with 31 days with the delivery dates from the raw data sheet.

On the main sheet I have a row date (from day 1 to day 31) and a row with the delivery date.

Currently I do 31 Querys:

```
=IFNA(QUERY(rawdata!A$2:B;"SELECT A WHERE B = date '"&TEXT(A2;"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' LIMIT 1"))
```

Is there a way to do it only with one Query instead of 31 Querys?

Link to the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mEuEaK8SoXlqzT3VsmZ0CEN2XFVzjupFpcgu2NMCRUI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go with:

```
=index(xlookup(A2:A;rawdata!B:B;rawdata!A:A;))
```

[image]

Comment: Wooow that solution was fast. Many thanks for your quick help.

Comment: Is it possible that XLOOKUP and INDEX shows a second row from the source table? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mEuEaK8SoXlqzT3VsmZ0CEN2XFVzjupFpcgu2NMCRUI/edit#gid=548185244

Comment: Try: `=map(A3:A;lambda(Σ;if(Σ="";;index(xlookup(Σ;rawdata!B:B;{rawdata!A:A\rawdata!C:C};)))))`